# Работы с событиями

Tags: c#, события

В своей программе, для упрощения кода, создал класс, куда запихнул все однотипные функции. Так вот, в этом классе есть свои объекты, у которых есть события. И мне необходимо передавать какую-то информацию, из этих событий в основную программу. Как с этим быть? Раньше просто всё было в основной программе и я использовал глобальные переменные, или вызывал функции в этих событиях. А когда всё это отдельно. Скорее всего, нужно создать событие в основной программе, которое я буду вызывать, когда будет вызываться событие в классе и передавать в основную программу во входных данных всю нужную информацию. Но как это реализовать в коде?
Заранее спасибо.

Например :

```
        publisherMove = new Publisher(conn, "p2mq://FORTS_SRV;category=FORTS_MSG;name=srvlinkMove;timeout=5000;scheme=|FILE|forts_messages.ini|message");
        listenerSendMove = new Listener(conn, "p2mqreply://;ref=srvlinkMove");
        listenerSendMove.Handler += new Listener.MessageHandler(ClientMessageCallbackMove);

       public static int ClientMessageCallbackMove(Connection conn, Listener listener, Message msg)
    {
        try
        {
            if (msg.Type == MessageType.MsgData)
            {
                DataMessage replmsg = (DataMessage)msg;
                //Здесь нужно передать в основную программу replmsg
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Client received reply [id: {0}, data: {1}, user-id: {2}, name: {3}]", ((DataMessage)msg).MsgId, ((DataMessage)msg).Data, ((DataMessage)msg).UserId, ((DataMessage)msg).MsgName));
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("client dump: {0}", msg);
                }
            }
            else if (msg.Type == MessageType.MsgP2MQTimeout)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Client reply TIMEOUT");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Message {0}", msg.Type));
            }
            return 0;
        }
        catch (CGateException e)
        {
            return (int)e.ErrCode;
        }
    }
```

Этот код в классе, мне не нужно полностью подписаться на это событие, мне нужно лишь от туда достать replmsg при его вызове.

Comment: Talk is cheap. Show me the code (c)

Comment: Так подписывайся в программе на эти события и дело с концом.

Comment: @Сергей Фишка в том, что в событии очень много условий и вариантов решения. Образно говорят, результат действия положительный, отрицательный и т п. Мне нужно именно, если результат в событии положительный. Весь код я не хочу переписывать сам. Как в этом быть?

Comment: Ну так пробрасывайте результат в событии и когда обрабатывать будете - смотрите и правильным образом реагируйте.

Comment: @Сергей я вас не понял, что именно делать.. Я добавил описание в пост еще

Comment: @SerafimProzorov добавил код

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так, если `listenerSendMove` - публичный объект, тогда возьмите и подпишитесь так же из вне вашего класса:

```
listenerSendMove.Handler += new  Listener.MessageHandler(AnotherClientMessageCallbackMove);

public static void ClientMessageCallbackMove(Connection conn, Listener listener, Message msg)
{

            DataMessage replmsg = (DataMessage)msg; //и делайте с ним что хотите

}
```

В чем проблема то я не пойму?

Comment: Спасибо, я думал, как-то не подписываясь на событие, изобретать какой-то велосипед и т п. А, в принципе, всё намного проще.

Comment: @Fresto, можно без подписки с помощью оборачивания события в TaskCompletionSource